# Turn off monitor using JNA

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Java program that turns off my computer monitor. From my research, it seems like the best way to go about this is to use JNA to call the WIN32API. Unfortunately, I'm a bit lost on how to do this, even after reading through as many resources related to this as I could find.

So far, I've added jna.jar to my project, but I'm completely lost as to how to use it in order to access the WIN32API and turn off my monitor.

Comment: Excatly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662079/how-do-you-turn-on-and-off-a-monitor-from-within-a-java-application

Comment: I saw that, and it's what lead me to look into JNA, but it doesn't answer the question I asked. The question there was how to turn your monitor off with Java, and one answer was to use a C-JNI wrapper, and another was to use JNA. Neither of those answers explain how to use JNA to turn off your monitor, only that you can use JNA.