# JNA - How to call System-functions? (rotate, screen off)

Tags: java, jna

I am completely new to the JNA interface (? library?) - but I see some of the System-functions are only accessible in Java via JNA. I wanna do some display-stuff, namely rotating and turn-off-monitor. For both function I have to call some system-functions - for the turn-off-monitor I found the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662079/how-do-you-turn-on-and-off-a-monitor-from-within-a-java-application) as well as for the rotate the [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/29c54d87-ee22-4051-9b33-db9559d40b72/changing-screen-orientation-programmatically-by-180-degree). But to be honest, I have no real clue how to start with one of them.

Could somebody give an idea how to start resp. how to implement?

Comment: Have you worked with the JNA library for any purpose yet? Have you gotten it to work for anything yet? And this statement is not true: `"...some of the System-functions are only accessible in Java via JNA."` as there is always more than one way to solve a problem, here including using JNI, or interfacing with an external utility.

Comment: What you're really asking in a nutshell is, "how do I use the JNA library", and for that you need to work with it a bit, learn it, go through its documentation, etc...

Comment: what you write is understandable, especially with external utility. And no, I didn't work up till now with JNA. JNI is out of scope cause C is inaccessible due to various reasons. Therefore I thought JNA is an approach. And, yeah, starting point is always the issue, but my question goes in the direction if I could use these samples - something I wanna have - instead of theoretical samples. And if so, how to start?

Comment: Yes, you can use those examples, for the most part, but first you will need to learn how to use the JNA library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I had to try the monitor on and off bit, and it worked! Too cool!

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class TurnOffMonitor {
   public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
      User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
      int SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170;
      int SC_MONITOR_OFF = 2;
      int SC_MONITOR_ON = -1;

      LRESULT SendMessageA(HWND paramHWND, int paramInt, WPARAM paramWPARAM,
            LPARAM paramLPARAM);

      LRESULT SendMessageA(HWND paramHWND, int paramInt, int paramInt2,
            LPARAM paramLPARAM);
   }

   private static final long SLEEP_TIME = 4 * 1000; // 4 seconds

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
      System.out.println("Foo");

      user32.SendMessageA(WinUser.HWND_BROADCAST, WinUser.WM_SYSCOMMAND,
            User32.SC_MONITORPOWER, new LPARAM(User32.SC_MONITOR_OFF));

      try {
         Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

      user32.SendMessageA(WinUser.HWND_BROADCAST, WinUser.WM_SYSCOMMAND,
            User32.SC_MONITORPOWER, new LPARAM(User32.SC_MONITOR_ON));

   }
}
```

Comment: Cool. works great - thx for the Christmas present ;)

Comment: Why are there two mappings of `SendMessageA`? The first one looks correct, the second one substitutes a 32-bit `int` for an integer pointer which may be 32 or 64 bits.